# Display <div> according to z-index value

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to display the `photoCaption` div every time the mouse is over an image with the `z-index == 19`.
However the code I've developed has 2 problems.

1. It displays the div `photoCaption` on all the images
2. When mouse is out, and mouse is over again, the `div` is not displayed any more.

What I'm doing wrong? The 2nd line of javascript code is probably wrong since it's always true.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mgJLp/4/) is the code

Comment: The photoCaption div is added to all images, because you have used a generic selector ($('img')). to add only to specific images then add a class to those images and use class selector to apply css.

Comment: How are you going to associate a unique caption with each image?

Comment: You're both right! I forgot the relative position of the images. The problem is already solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First issue, your conditional statmenet should be:

```
if($(this).css('z-index') == 19) { // you're using $('img') which returns all img elements and then you're setting the z-index to 19 for all of them.
```

but `z-index` will read `auto` unless you add `position` to the `img` elements. So add:

```
img{
    position: relative;
}
```

You've also set `display` to `display`, which is incorrect, it should read:

```
display: 'block', // could also be inline, inline-block etc
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mgJLp/5/

Answer (score 1):

To correct the issue with the caption only showing once, change your mouseover event to:

```
$('img').bind('mousemove', function (e) {
    if ($('img').css('z-index') == '19') {
        $('#photoCaption').css({
            display: 'block',
            left: e.pageX + 20,
            top: e.pageY,
            'z-index': 100
        });
    }
});
```

The display property gets set to `block` to show the caption div.

As for only displaying the caption on images with a z-index of 19, using the z-index as a means of distinguishing elements isn't ideal. Using a class selector if possible would be easier.

As it stands, with your current javascript, you are setting the z-index rather than checking it. Check out the new condition above `$('img').css('z-index') == '19'`

Answer (score 0):

Solves Both your problems..

```
$('img').css('position','relative');
$('img').on('mousemove', function (e) {
    if ($(this).css('zIndex')=='19') {
        $('#photoCaption').css({
            display: 'block',
            left: e.pageX + 20,
            top: e.pageY,
            'z-index': 100
        });
    }
});

$('img').mouseout(function () {
    $('#photoCaption').css({
        display: 'none'
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/writetobhuwan/mgJLp/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').bind('mousemove', function (e) {
    if ($(this).css('zIndex', 19)) {
        $('#photoCaption').css({
            display: 'block',
            left: e.pageX + 20,
            top: e.pageY,
            'z-index': 100
        });
    }
    $(this).mouseout(function () {
    $('#photoCaption').css({
        display: 'none'
    });
})
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mgJLp/7/)